# Getting a blank output from mysql. Never used "%s" before

Tags: php, mysql, insert

My question is whether or not I am using %s properly or if it has to be something else for my variables? (I am getting no record added in my database)

The Entries:

```
$login = "coolkidz";
$sname = "heyu";
$city = "beautiful";
$pass = "awesome";
$username = "what";
$mcode = "nice";
```

The query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO login(sname, city, pass, username, mcode, username) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", $sname, $city, $pass, $username, $mcode, $login);
```

Here's the echo that doesn't emit anything

```
echo "'INSERT INTO login(sname, city, pass, username, mcode, username) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')', $sname, $city, $pass, $username, $mcode, $login");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO login(sname, city, pass, username, mcode, username) VALUES('$sname','$city','$pass','$username','$mcode','$login')");
```

Comment: be sure to know what contain your variables because this can open the door to some sql injection.

Comment: yes. I'm just trying to get this working. But the above didn't work. Thanks, but yours didn't work either (no mysql entry).